# Oracle SQL Correlated Subquery (in WHERE statement) having no results

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, subquery, correlated-subquery

Hi and thanks for reading,

I am trying to run the following SQL query with correlated subquery and it is bringing back no results.  I am using the subquery to only bring back results that have the lowest date range.  Both the query alone and the subquery alone work fine.

Any ideas?  Am I linking the correlated subquery incorrectly?

Note: The correlated subquery is on the last line of the query

Thank you,
Willz06jw

```
SELECT aaa."effective_time", 
       aaa."event_type_c", 
       "clarity_dep"."department_name", 
       "patient"."birth_date", 
       "patient"."pat_mrn_id", 
       "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."name", 
       "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."ped_delivr_meth_c", 
       aaa."department_id", 
       "clarity_dep"."department_id", 
       aaa."alt_event_type_c", 
       aaa."in_event_type_c" 
FROM   (("CLARITY"."clarity_adt" aaa 
         inner join "CLARITY"."clarity_dep" "CLARITY_DEP" 
                 ON aaa."department_id" = "clarity_dep"."department_id") 
        inner join "CLARITY"."patient" "PATIENT" 
                ON aaa."pat_id" = "patient"."pat_id") 
       inner join "CLARITY"."zc_ped_delivr_meth" "ZC_PED_DELIVR_METH" 
               ON "patient"."ped_delivr_meth_c" = 
                  "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."ped_delivr_meth_c" 
WHERE  ( "patient"."birth_date" >= To_date ('01-12-2012 00:00:00', 
                                            'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
         AND "patient"."birth_date" < To_date ('06-12-2012 00:00:00', 
                                      'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' 
                                      ) ) 
       AND ( aaa."department_id" = 236601 
              OR aaa."department_id" = 236703 
              OR aaa."department_id" = 236801 
              OR aaa."department_id" = 236901 
              OR aaa."department_id" = 237101 
              OR aaa."department_id" = 237201 ) 
       AND aaa."event_type_c" = 3 
       AND aaa."effective_time" = (SELECT Min(bbb."effective_time") 
                                   FROM   "clarity_adt" bbb 
                                   WHERE  aaa."pat_id" = bbb.pat_id)
```

Comment: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm is your friend.

Comment: The best guess is that the minimum effective_time is not for one of the listed departments or event types.  The `where` clause only affects the outer query.

Comment: `"clarity_adt" bbb  WHERE  aaa."pat_id" = bbb.pat_id` so are there two columns in "clarity_adt"? as you've put lowercase pat_id on one side (quoted), and what will be uppercase on the other.

Comment: @DazzaL: so I should do it like: `CLARITY_ADT bbb where aaa.PAT_ID = bbb.pat_id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without zifting through the entire statement, the easiest solution would be to just wrap the statement in a select using the `ROW_NUMBER` function to get the lowest dates.

**SQL Statement 1**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY effective_time) AS rn,
                 aaa."effective_time", 
                 aaa."event_type_c", 
                 "clarity_dep"."department_name", 
                 "patient"."birth_date", 
                 "patient"."pat_mrn_id", 
                 "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."name", 
                 "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."ped_delivr_meth_c", 
                 aaa."department_id", 
                 "clarity_dep"."department_id", 
                 aaa."alt_event_type_c", 
                 aaa."in_event_type_c" 
          FROM   "CLARITY"."clarity_adt" aaa
                 inner join "CLARITY"."clarity_dep" "CLARITY_DEP" ON aaa."department_id" = "clarity_dep"."department_id"
                 inner join "CLARITY"."patient" "PATIENT" ON aaa."pat_id" = "patient"."pat_id"
                 inner join "CLARITY"."zc_ped_delivr_meth" "ZC_PED_DELIVR_METH" ON "patient"."ped_delivr_meth_c" = "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."ped_delivr_meth_c"
          WHERE  ( "patient"."birth_date" >= To_date ('01-12-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                 AND "patient"."birth_date" < To_date ('06-12-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) ) 
                 AND ( aaa."department_id" = 236601 OR aaa."department_id" = 236703 OR aaa."department_id" = 236801 OR aaa."department_id" = 236901 OR aaa."department_id" = 237101 OR aaa."department_id" = 237201 ) 
                 AND aaa."event_type_c" = 3 
        ) q
WHERE   q.rn = 1
```

Your statement could be simplified *(in reading it)* by using an `IN` statement io. all the `OR`statements like such

**SQL Statement 2**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY effective_time) AS rn,
                 aaa."effective_time", 
                 aaa."event_type_c", 
                 "clarity_dep"."department_name", 
                 "patient"."birth_date", 
                 "patient"."pat_mrn_id", 
                 "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."name", 
                 "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."ped_delivr_meth_c", 
                 aaa."department_id", 
                 "clarity_dep"."department_id", 
                 aaa."alt_event_type_c", 
                 aaa."in_event_type_c" 
          FROM   "CLARITY"."clarity_adt" aaa
                 inner join "CLARITY"."clarity_dep" "CLARITY_DEP" ON aaa."department_id" = "clarity_dep"."department_id"
                 inner join "CLARITY"."patient" "PATIENT" ON aaa."pat_id" = "patient"."pat_id"
                 inner join "CLARITY"."zc_ped_delivr_meth" "ZC_PED_DELIVR_METH" ON "patient"."ped_delivr_meth_c" = "zc_ped_delivr_meth"."ped_delivr_meth_c"
          WHERE  ( "patient"."birth_date" >= To_date ('01-12-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                 AND "patient"."birth_date" < To_date ('06-12-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) ) 
                 AND ( aaa."department_id" IN (236601,236703,236801,236901,237101,237201) )
                 AND aaa."event_type_c" = 3 
        ) q
WHERE   q.rn = 1
```

In the end, I would even simplify it further by aliassing all tables and use a `WITH` statement. The final result would look like this

**SQL Statement 3**

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pat_id ORDER BY effective_time) AS rn,
         aaa."effective_time", 
         aaa."event_type_c", 
         cd."department_name", 
         p."birth_date", 
         p."pat_mrn_id", 
         pdm."name", 
         pdm."ped_delivr_meth_c", 
         aaa."department_id", 
         cd."department_id", 
         aaa."alt_event_type_c", 
         aaa."in_event_type_c" 
  FROM   "CLARITY"."clarity_adt" aaa
         inner join "CLARITY"."clarity_dep" cd ON aaa."department_id" = cd."department_id"
         inner join "CLARITY"."patient" p ON aaa."pat_id" = p."pat_id"
         inner join "CLARITY"."zc_ped_delivr_meth" pdm ON p."ped_delivr_meth_c" = pdm."ped_delivr_meth_c"
  WHERE  p."birth_date" >= To_date ('01-12-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
         AND p."birth_date" < To_date ('06-12-2012 00:00:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS' ) ) 
         AND aaa."department_id" IN (236601,236703,236801,236901,237101,237201)
         AND aaa."event_type_c" = 3 
)
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: When I use SQL Statement 3 -- it says the last SELECT statement has a column that is ambiguously defined

Comment: @WillHoward - Aliassing either the `aaa."departmentid"` or the `cd."department_id"` should resolve that error.

Comment: Crap that is impressive.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're only going to get rows if the row with the earliest date also matches the other conditions on clarity_adt. If you want the earliest record for that subset then you'd have to push those conditions into the subquery.

Comment: I tried this and it didnt work:  `aaa.EFFECTIVE_TIME = (select min(bbb.EFFECTIVE_TIME) from CLARITY_ADT bbb where aaa.PAT_ID = bbb.pat_id AND ( aaa.department_id IN (236601,236703,236801,236901,237101,237201) )
 AND aaa.EVENT_TYPE_C=3 )`